# Acessing a locally declared struct outside of its scope

Tags: c, struct

I want to write data to an array of structures. The structure itself is declared and defined inside main(). I have three functions that need to write, process and read the data from the array.
All I could achieve was creating a global struct declaration and then passing pointers to them.

Is it possible without making the structure declaration global?

The relevant code is posted below.

This is my struct declaration outside of main()

```
struct date
{
    int d;
    int m;
    int y;
};

struct stud
{
    int roll;
    char name[30];
    struct date dob;
    int P;
    int C;
    int M;
    float PCM;
    char flag_in;
    char flag_pro;
};
```

These are the function definitions.

```
void getdata(struct stud *S)
{
    scanf("%d", &(S->roll));
    scanf("%s", (S->name));
    // Similarly for dob, p, c, m
    (S->flag_in) = '1';
    return;
}

void process(struct stud *S)
{
    if(S->flag_in == '1')
    {
        S->PCM = (S->P + S->C + S->M)/3;
        S->flag_pro = '1';
    }
}

void display(struct stud *S)
{
    for(int x=0; x<10; x++)
        if(S[x].flag_in == '1')
        {
            // Printing the data to the console output
        }
}
```

These are the function calls:

```
getdata(&S[i]);
process(&S[x]);
display(S);
```

Comment: As long as you're passing pointers around, there's nothing stopping you from declaring it on the stack (as a local variable) in main, and passing the pointer to *that*.

Comment: @sapi How would this work? Wouldn't the receiving function's declaration/definition need to see the type of the argument it's receiving?

Comment: What you _can_ do is have a file with the struct definition and the functions that need to work with the data inside the struct, and then just pass around pointers. Then you could keep all internal things local and hidden.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy Upvoted. See my sketch of your approach below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have your structure within the `main()` then the scope of this structure is local to `main()`.
Since structures are user-defined data-types, it can't used as you try because this new type is just visible within the `main()`.

So the functions which you have defined will not have visibility of the structure.

So in order to handle this the structure should be made global.

So a binary answer to your question

> Is it possible without making the structure declaration global?

is ***no***.

Comment: Thanks. But I achieved it in an unsafe way by passing the address of struct to a pointer in the function and then manually moving the required number of bytes to access the variables of the struct. I think the best is what you're saying.

Answer (score 2):

It's entirely valid to not want to expose other parts of your program to the internal structure of a type.

C is extremely well placed to do this with considerable elegance.

Call this X.h

```
//Declaration of X as pointing to an incomplete struct XS.
//This says there's such a thing as a struct XS but not how it is laid out or even how big it is.
//It also says X is a short-hand for a pointer to a mysterious XS structure. 
typedef struct XS* X;

//Creates an X and returns a pointer to it. Remember to call destroyX(.) exactly once - later.    
X createX(void);
//Does something with X and returns some number.
int doXThing(X x);

//Destroys an X. Must be called exactly once for each return value from createX().
void destroyX(X x);
```

This is prog.c (containing your `main(.)` function).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "X.h"

//Now we actually define that mysterious structure.
//Other translation units will not see this.
struct XS {
    int v;
} ;

//Here we have size and layout so we can actually implement it.

X createX(void){
    X x=malloc(sizeof(struct XS));//Explicit allocation of 'implementation struct'.
    if(x==NULL){
        return NULL;//malloc(.) failed.
    }
    x->v=0;
    return x;
}

int doXThing(X x){
    return (x->v)++;
}

void destroyX(X x){
    free(x);
}

int main(void) {
    X x=createX();

    printf("%d\n",doXThing(x));
    printf("%d\n",doXThing(x));
    printf("%d\n",doXThing(x));

    destroyX(x);

    return 0;
}
```

Notice that the other modules using `#include "X.h"` don't see the layout of the structures.
The upside is the implementation can change normally without recompilation - just re-linking.
The downside is that without access to the size and layout of X those 'using' modules need to delegate all the work to a module that does!
That means all Xs have to come of the free-store (or a static pool inside the implementing module..).

This model is really rather common and quite powerful as it allows for complete abstraction and data hiding.

If you're willing to do a load of casting you don't even need to 'reveal' the name `XS`.

```
typedef XSHandle* X;
```

Or even

```
typedef unsigned short* X; //Little used type... Illegal but works on most platforms - check your documentation of use char (bare, signed or unsigned).
```

But don't get led into:

```
typedef void* X;
```

In C. `void*` is so promiscuous in its casting you will get into trouble!
C++ however behaves far better about that.

**PS:** It's not normal to put the implementation in the same translation unit as `main(.)`.
It's not wrong in a small project but it's not normal to get into quite so much abstraction in a small project.

**PPS:** A stated this method provides for a very high degree of OO programming. It may be of interest that Stroustrup made documented design decisions to NOT do this for all classes in C++ because it has a fixed and unavoidable overhead and he gave himself a 'zero-overhead principle' and wanted to provide a way of 'mixing' abstraction with direct access to object layout (allocation as local variable, direct access to members, inline functions,...).

I think he made the right decision as a language level decision for the intended use of C++. That doesn't make it a bad design pattern where appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the approach but this is too advanced for me as of now. It sure is a nice way for abstraction.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is declare the struct inside the main. and pass the pointer when the functions are called:

```
//this code is inside main
struct stud arr[10]; // create an array for the struct
display(arr); //pass the pointer to function
```

since the main is called before the functions the data will not be deleted and will exist on the processing of other functions which can pass the pointer between them.

Although I suggest not to use this method if the functions are not for one purpose (change value, print, etc...). If the data struct is used as global declare it as global.

Comment: Thanks. But I guess the only NICE and STANDARD way is to make the definition global. I did try something similar as you are saying and it worked fine. I used a char* p and moved the pointer by required number of bytes to access the next element of the struct but that was a very cumbersome and hard to maintain code.

Answer (score 1):

I have the impression that you are not clear on the difference between the definition of a `struct` type and an instance of that type.

To be able to work with a `struct` variable, your functions have to see the full type declaration, such that the compiler knows how the variable is structured and to access the different fields. But there is no need that they see the variable declaration as such. The variable can be accessed without problems through a pointer that you pass as argument.

Comment: Thanks. I do know that the functions need to know the type they are being passed and for that they need the struct declaration. But I was hoping for a way to access the struct without making it global.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible without making the structure declaration global?

No, any function needs a `struct`'s definition to be visible (globally) for it to be usable. Otherwise, from the function's viewpoint, the invisible `struct` would be an undefined identifier.

Local structs will not be visible anywhere outside the function.

The more important question would be: What do you save in making it local as opposed to global? One thing that comes to my mind is that compilation time *might* be faster since if declared global in a header where lot of [translation units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit) see it unnecessarily.

Comment: Thanks. I see that I need to make it global to have a SAFE implementation. I did it without a global definition using a char *p and passing the address of the struct to the function and moving it by required number of bytes manually to access the next variable in the struct. I think it worked only because all the function calls are within main's scope so that the data in the struct isn't destroyed and is available to access using a pointer.